# Octave in Jupyter Notebook - Opening 3D plot in an external window for interactive use

Tags: plot, jupyter-notebook, gnuplot, octave

Is it possible using Octave in Jupyter Notebook to open plots in an external window so that they can be manipulated (zooming in/out, rotating)?

I hoped there would be some switch so that I could use them inline (as it is by default) but if need be, I could open them in an external window to manipulate it the way like in GNU Octave GUI. After checking what I need, I would switch back to inline.

I looked for some hints. I found this `%%octave -g` in [octavemagic: Octave inside IPython](https://notebook.community/blink1073/oct2py/example/octavemagic_extension). Unforutunately, it doesn't work for me when using Octave kernel.

I found something about inline plotting in [An Octave kernel for Jupyter](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel) (Configuration section) but it doesn't look like it could help anything in regard to switching on/off it from the notebook.

For example, I would like the following code to invoke an external window.

```
y=-10:0.4:10+eps;
[xx,yy]=meshgrid(x,y);
zz= sin(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2))./(sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2));

surf(xx,yy,zz)
view(-35,45)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that I have finally found the answer here:

- https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/98
- https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/6
- https://am111.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jmatlab_use.html

`%plot gnuplot` - switch to using external window

`%plot inline` - switch to using inline plotting